# Como colocar o valor de uma variável PHP dentro de um input?

Tags: php, html, input

Como colocar o valor de uma variável (já calculada em PHP) dentro de um *input*?

```
<form method="post" action="calculos.php">
<div id="circulantes">
    <div class="ativocirculante" id="ativocirculante">
        <h2>ATIVO CIRCULANTE<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="ac" readonly/></h2>
        <h4>Ativo Errático (Financeiro) <input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00 aplicações" id="ae"/></h4>
        <h4>Disponíveis (Caixa e Bancos)<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="disp"/></h4>
        <h3>ACO<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="aco" readonly/></h3>
        <h4>Contas a receber<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr" name="ncr" value="<?php echo $crTot;?>" readonly/></h4>
        <h4 id="cr1">Até 30 dias<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr11" name="ncr11"/></h4>
        <h4 id="cr2">31 a 60 dias<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr22" name="ncr22"/></h4>
        <h4 id="cr3">61 a 90 dias<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr33" name="ncr33"/></h4>
        <h4 id="cr4">Acima de 90 dias<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr44" name="ncr44"/></h4>
        <h4>Estoque<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="est"/></h4>
        <h4>Adiantamento a Fornecedores<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="af"/></h4>
        <h4>Despesas antecipadas<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="da"/></h4>
        <input type="submit" value="calcular">
    </div>


<?php
$crTot = "";
if(isset($_POST)){
    $cr1 = $_POST['ncr11'];
    $cr2 = $_POST['ncr22'];
    $cr3 = $_POST['ncr33'];
    $cr4 = $_POST['ncr44'];
    $crTot = $cr1+$cr2+$cr3+$cr4;
    echo $crTot;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use o "value=valor"

Ex.:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr33" name="ncr33" value=<?php echo $variavel ?>/>
```

Faça assim:

```
<?php
$crTot = "";
if(isset($_POST)){
    $cr1 = $_POST['ncr11'];
    $cr2 = $_POST['ncr22'];
    $cr3 = $_POST['ncr33'];
    $cr4 = $_POST['ncr44'];
    $crTot = $cr1+$cr2+$cr3+$cr4;
    echo $crTot;
}
?>
<form method="post" action="calculos.php">
<div id="circulantes">
.....
restante do código
```

Comment: Mas já foi feito isso, então qual é o problema?

Comment: A desculpe, dentro do input aparece a seguinte mensagem: (<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: crTot in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\menuVertical\apCirculantes.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />)

Comment: Isso quer dizer que não foi definida a variável !
Você definiu a variável antes de tentar imprimir ?

Comment: Adicione o código PHP antes do form

Comment: Sim, acredito que ela esteja definida no código abaixo: <?php
$crTot = "";
if(isset($_POST)){
    $cr1 = $_POST['ncr11'];
    $cr2 = $_POST['ncr22'];
    $cr3 = $_POST['ncr33'];
    $cr4 = $_POST['ncr44'];
    $crTot = $cr1+$cr2+$cr3+$cr4;
    echo $crTot;
}

Comment: Coloca o código PHP antes do form, e não esqueça de fechar:
<?php
$crTot = "";
if(isset($_POST)){....
} ?>

Comment: o código em PHP está adicionado numa página chamada "calculos.php" e e meu action está chamando esta função.

Comment: Sim mas essas definições $cr1 = $_POST['ncr11'], etc tem que ficar antes do seu form

Comment: Veja a adição que fiz

Comment: Certo, coloquei antes do form e agora desapareceu a mensagem de "Undefined variable", mas ela não está calculando a soma das demais.

Comment: esta input (<h4>Contas a receber<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr" name="ncr" value="<?php echo $crTot;?>" readonly/></h4>) deveria aparecer dentro dela o valor da soma das demais, correto? Se sim, tem algum erro pq ela está nula...

Comment: Aí é problema de como está trazendo pelo POST.
Para testar pode fazer assim: $cr1 = 1;
    $cr2 = 2;
    $cr3 = 3;
    $cr4 = 4;
Terá que aparecer 10

Comment: Deu certo Raoni BZ, mas por que não está rolando com o POST?

Comment: Aí seria problema de como você está enviando e buscando com o POST.
Marque essa questão como encerrada, abra outra para vermos o problema do POST.

Comment: Ok! marcarei. obrigado

Comment: Pessoal, desculpem-me mas sou iniciante neste site. Como faço para finalizar uma pergunta?

Comment: Não sei se ainda é assim, mas nunca abri perguntas.

https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta

Comment: Tem um " V " abaixo das setas ao lado da resposta, não tem ?!

Comment: Ok, finalizei e criei outro para o POST.

Comment: Para simplificar 
<?=$variavel?>

Comment: @RobertoGóes claro, pode também!

Answer (score 5):

Você está fazendo certo, mas na ordem errada. O que acontece é que você não declarou a variável `$crTot` antes de tentar usa-la. Para consertar, só inverter a ordem do `php` com o `HTML`:

```
<?php
$crTot = ""; //Aqui ele está criando a variável, a partir daqui, ela pode ser usada.
if(isset($_POST)){
    $cr1 = $_POST['ncr11'];
    $cr2 = $_POST['ncr22'];
    $cr3 = $_POST['ncr33'];
    $cr4 = $_POST['ncr44'];
    $crTot = $cr1+$cr2+$cr3+$cr4;
    echo $crTot;
}
?>
<form method="post" action="calculos.php">
<div id="circulantes">
    <div class="ativocirculante" id="ativocirculante">
        <h2>ATIVO CIRCULANTE<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="ac" readonly/></h2>
        <h4>Ativo Errático (Financeiro) <input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00 aplicações" id="ae"/></h4>
        <h4>Disponíveis (Caixa e Bancos)<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="disp"/></h4>
        <h3>ACO<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="aco" readonly/></h3>
        <h4>Contas a receber<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr" name="ncr" value="<?php echo $crTot; ?>" readonly/></h4>
        <h4 id="cr1">Até 30 dias<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr11" name="ncr11"/></h4>
        <h4 id="cr2">31 a 60 dias<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr22" name="ncr22"/></h4>
        <h4 id="cr3">61 a 90 dias<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr33" name="ncr33"/></h4>
        <h4 id="cr4">Acima de 90 dias<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr44" name="ncr44"/></h4>
        <h4>Estoque<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="est"/></h4>
        <h4>Adiantamento a Fornecedores<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="af"/></h4>
        <h4>Despesas antecipadas<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="da"/></h4>
        <input type="submit" value="calcular">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oi Francisco, neste caso a página me retorna isso: Notice: Undefined index: ncr11 in C:\xampp\htdocs\menuVertical\apCirculantes.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: ncr22 in C:\xampp\htdocs\menuVertical\apCirculantes.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: ncr33 in C:\xampp\htdocs\menuVertical\apCirculantes.php on line 22

Notice: Undefined index: ncr44 in C:\xampp\htdocs\menuVertical\apCirculantes.php on line 23
0

Answer (score 1):

Use o `isset` também na variável `$crTot` e identifique a variável no post como por exemplo `$_POST['ncr11']`, fiz o seguinte código para ajuda-ló:

```
<form method="post" action="calculos.php">
    <div id="circulantes">
        <div class="ativocirculante" id="ativocirculante">
            <h2>ATIVO CIRCULANTE<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="ac" readonly/></h2>
            <h4>Ativo Errático (Financeiro) <input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00 aplicações" id="ae"/></h4>
            <h4>Disponíveis (Caixa e Bancos)<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="disp"/></h4>
            <h3>ACO<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="aco" readonly/></h3>
            <h4>Contas a receber<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr" name="ncr" value="<?php if(isset($crTot)){ echo $crTot; } ?>" readonly/></h4>
            <h4 id="cr1">Até 30 dias<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr11" name="ncr11"/></h4>
            <h4 id="cr2">31 a 60 dias<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr22" name="ncr22"/></h4>
            <h4 id="cr3">61 a 90 dias<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr33" name="ncr33"/></h4>
            <h4 id="cr4">Acima de 90 dias<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr44" name="ncr44"/></h4>
            <h4>Estoque<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="est"/></h4>
            <h4>Adiantamento a Fornecedores<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="af"/></h4>
            <h4>Despesas antecipadas<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="da"/></h4>
            <input type="submit" value="calcular">
        </div>


    <?php
    $crTot = "";
    if(isset($_POST['ncr11'])){
        $cr1 = $_POST['ncr11'];
        $cr2 = $_POST['ncr22'];
        $cr3 = $_POST['ncr33'];
        $cr4 = $_POST['ncr44'];
        $crTot = $cr1+$cr2+$cr3+$cr4;
        echo $crTot;
    }
    ?>
</form>
```

Fiz este código levando em consideração que esta pagina se chama `calculos.php`.

Comment: Desta forma resolve o problema dele, porque o erro é por causa que não encontra a variável $crTot, e para evitar algum warning coloquei para verificar o $_POST['ncr11'].