# Não consigo retornar para a input o valor de um POST em PHP

Tags: php, post, input

Tenho um formulário com quatro campos numéricos, `ncr11`, `ncr22`, `ncr33` e `ncr44`. Ainda há outro campo no formulário, `ncr`, que receberá um valor total, que corresponde à soma de todos os quatros primeiros campos. A soma eu fiz com PHP e fui informado em [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/242426/5878) que deveria manter o `action` do formulário em branco e executar o código na mesma página, porém, ao atualizar a página, meu campo resultado sempre acaba ficando em branco.

O que eu gostaria de fazer é que quando o usuário entrasse com os valores, o campo resultado fosse atualizado automaticamente.

```
<?php
$crTot = "";
if($_POST){
    $cr1 = $_POST['ncr11'];
    $cr2 = $_POST['ncr22'];
    $cr3 = $_POST['ncr33'];
    $cr4 = $_POST['ncr44'];
$crTot = $cr1+$cr2+$cr3+$cr4;
echo $crTot;
}
?>

<form method="post" action="">
<div id="circulantes">
    <div class="ativocirculante" id="ativocirculante">
        <h2>ATIVO CIRCULANTE<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="ac" readonly/></h2>
        <h4>Ativo Errático (Financeiro) <input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00 aplicações" id="ae"/></h4>
        <h4>Disponíveis (Caixa e Bancos)<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="disp"/></h4>
        <h3>ACO<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="aco" readonly/></h3>
        <h4>Contas a receber<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr" name="ncr" value="<?php echo $crTot;?>" readonly/></h4>
        <h4 id="cr1">Até 30 dias<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr11" name="ncr11"/></h4>
        <h4 id="cr2">31 a 60 dias<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr22" name="ncr22"/></h4>
        <h4 id="cr3">61 a 90 dias<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr33" name="ncr33"/></h4>
        <h4 id="cr4">Acima de 90 dias<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr44" name="ncr44"/></h4>
        <h4>Estoque<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="est"/></h4>
        <h4>Adiantamento a Fornecedores<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="af"/></h4>
        <h4>Despesas antecipadas<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="da"/></h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Essas somas no `$crTot` não vão funcionar bem se o que está escrito nas caixas segue o formato `R$ X,XX`

Comment: Bruce, por favor, leia o guia de [ask] o mais rápido possível. Eu abri um [debate no Meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6404/editar-é-melhor-que-fechar-mas-quando) para discutir o caso da sua outra pergunta, pois não era clara mas foi respondida.

Comment: Essa página é para trazer resultados correto ?
Mas qual o seu script antes dessa página, que trás "envia" os dados em POST ?
Ou na verdade, você teria que usar o GET se trouxer na URL

Comment: Pode por favor detalhar o erro? Que mensagem dá? o que vem no retorno...

Comment: Basicamente, estou criando uma forma do usuário ao digitar os valores dentro das inputs (ncr11 até ncr44) ela retorne a soma destas dentro da input (ncr). O problema é que quando carrego a página e digito valores testes dentro das inputs mencionadas, a input "ncr" fica em branco... Quando uso if (isset($_POST){...} a página retorna Notice: Undefined index: ncr11 in C:\xampp\htdocs\menuVertical\apCirculantes.php on line 20
Notice: Undefined index: ncr22 in C:\xampp\htdocs\menuVertical\apCirculantes.php on line 21

Comment: O `action` do seu formulário não esta sendo apontado para nenhuma página. Ou você esta fazendo o envio via `JQuery`?

Comment: Estava sendo apontado para a página calculos.php, mas foi instruído para trazer o código para antes do form, por testes. Dessa forma, deixei o action nulo

Comment: Bruce, você quer que apareça o resultado em tempo real ou apenas quando algum botão for pressionado?

Comment: Em tempo real, essa é a ideia.

Comment: Tomarei a liberdade de editar sua pergunta novamente para não ocorrer como na outra. Veja como ficará a edição e tome como base para suas perguntas futuras.

Comment: Ok Anderson, tudo que for pra ajudar será bem-vindo. Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Define uma máscara fixa para os campos de valor, use o plugin [jQuery Input Mask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) , ou use o input com `type='number'`, mas isso não funciona em vários navegadores, para travar um formato para número recomendo o plugin.

2 - `Action` em branco indica que você não usa `jQuery/Ajax` para submeter e quer que ele envie para a mesma página, então o PHP que recebe o `$_POST` deve ficar no topo do arquivo.

3 - Como disse no `'1'`, para funcionar você precisa de um padrão, ou seja, sempre `'RS10,00'`, ou `'10,00'`, ou `'10.00'`, não importa qual formato, o que importa é que input tenha sempre o mesmo formato.

Supondo que o seu input teria o formato `'RS10.00'`, use `str_replace()` par remover o `'R$'` e `number_format()` para formatar a string em um número decimal:

```
<?php

$crTot = "";
if($_POST){
    $cr1 =  number_format(str_replace('R$', '', $_POST['ncr11']), 2, '.', ' ');
    $cr2 =  number_format(str_replace('R$', '', $_POST['ncr22']), 2, '.', ' ');
    $cr3 =  number_format(str_replace('R$', '', $_POST['ncr33']), 2, '.', ' ');
    $cr4 =  number_format(str_replace('R$', '', $_POST['ncr44']), 2, '.', ' ');
    $crTot = $cr1+$cr2+$cr3+$cr4;
    echo $crTot;
}
?>
```

E para colocar esse valor dentro do input (você fez certo):

```
<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr" name="ncr" value="<?php echo $crTot;?>" readonly/>
```

Como atualizar automaticamente com JS:

Você precisa primeiro, adicionar alguns identificadores classnames aos elementos abaixo:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr" name="ncr" value="" class='ncrTot' readonly/>
<h4 id="cr1">Até 30 dias<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr11" name="ncr11" class='ncr11 ncr_value'/></h4>
<h4 id="cr2">31 a 60 dias<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr22" name="ncr22" class='ncr22 ncr_value' /></h4>
<h4 id="cr3">61 a 90 dias<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr33" name="ncr33" class='ncr33 ncr_value' /></h4>
<h4 id="cr4">Acima de 90 dias<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr44" name="ncr44" class='ncr44 ncr_value' /></h4>
```

Repare que foi aidicionado um classname 'ncr_value' aos 4 campos em questão.

Agora, para colocar um máscara que manterá um padrão ao valor, vamos usar o plugin jqueryinputmask, basta coloca isso dentro do `'<head>'` de sua página junto com o jQuery:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
              integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Agora, pra aplicar a máscara, insira o seguinte código em seu arquivo:

```
$('.ncr_value').inputmask('decimal', {
                'alias': 'numeric',
                'groupSeparator': ',',
                'autoGroup': true,
                'digits': 2,
                'radixPoint': ".",
                'digitsOptional': false,
                'allowMinus': false,
                'prefix': 'R$ '
    });
```

Se tudo ocorreu certo, nesse ponto você terá input com formato `'R$00.00'`.

Agora, pra fazer o calculo, existem diversas formas, no exemplo, será usado um loop pelos inputs, e evetuando uma soma dinamica:

```
//Indica para efetuar a soma quando for pressionado um botão com foco no input, quando o valor for alterado, ou qunado o foco seguir em diante
$(document).on('keyup blur change','.ncr_value',function(){
        var v = 0;  
        //Inicia o loop pelos cmapos
        $('.ncr_value').each(function(b,c) {   
        if ($(c).val()) {
        //Remove o 'R$' para converter em numero
        var a = $(c).val().replace('R$','');
        //Susbtitui a virgula padrão de milhares por nada para somar corretamente
        var b = a.replace(',','');
        //Usa o += para somar os valores
        v += parseFloat(b);
        }
    });
    //Preenche o elemento com classname 'ncrTot' com o resultado da soma.
    $('.ncrTot').val('R$' + v.toFixed(2));
});
```

Tentei explicar de forma simples um modo de se fazer isso, não sei se ficou tão simples, da pra melhorar e muito, segue um exemplo funcionando no fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jd8zz2kb/1/

Comment: Perfeito, já alterei da forma que você sugeriu. Aguardo novas instruções.

Comment: @BruceDuarte da uma olhada vc da pra entender agora.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado.